# Lost Record Focus in Grid when store is reload in ext.net

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

I am using Ext.Net. In Grid Row editable after the record focus is lost when new databind in particular record. My requirement is "How to set focus when store is reload "

Answer (score 0):

Try with the tag SelectionMemory="True" into the gridpanel configuration.